# Is there any reason why I should not finish before I build?

Tags: finishing, oiling

I want to finish some pine wood with Danish oil and then try and build a coffee table.

I was wondering if there is any reason to build before finishing. I realise that Im probably going to finish some scrap pieces that are going to be left over from the build. There may be more work than what is strictly neccesary. Im ok with that. The idea is to practice my finishing technique anyway.

All the youtube videos do the build first so Im not sure if there is a reason for that?

Comment: Hi Neil, welcome to Woodworking. Have a look at this Q&A, [Should I finish before, during, or after assembly?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/should-i-finish-before-during-or-after-assembly) which was closed as a duplicate of [At what stage of basic furniture making should I "finish" the wood?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/at-what-stage-of-basic-furniture-making-should-i-finish-the-wood)

Comment: This question is specific to danish oil finish

Comment: Make table parts, practice finish process on scraps from build?

Comment: @NeilMeyer There isn't anything in your question to differentiate it from the other questions about when to apply finish. Is there anything specific you can add to clarify the distinction between your question and the existing questions and their answers? For example, can you reference the other questions and clarify how those questions and/or their answers are inapplicable or fall short of answering your question?

Answer (score 2):

I do often prime and do one coat of paint on timber for house construction and then do a final coat after completion.  I do this since it's easier to prime and do the first coat before the timber is in place and for outdoor applications it keeps the timber from absorbing moisture and warping.

For indoor furniture, the danish-oil treated portions will not glue well and it can attract dust.  There is also the likelihood that in building the furniture that you get some small scratches and these will need to be sanded out which will require refinishing.

Comment: Could you do this if you screw the joints togethet?

Comment: Back priming wood siding is an _excellent_ idea, yet _very_ difficult to do once the siding has been installed. Good idea to prime/paint the end-grain of siding too, but, again, difficult once installed.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - yes, if you screw it together then the only reason to not pre-finish is to avoid damaging the components.  I am starting to wonder if I by "build" you mean assemble?  I was thinking you were talking about finishing the raw wood before you saw/drill it.